# Get Active Application Identifier

Tags: objective-c, bundle, jailbreak, identifier

My question differs than the other ones, because I am coding for a jailbroken environment. The method I am editing belongs to SpringBoard and creates a system wide change, on all apps. Using this command:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]
```

Only brings SpringBoard, as this method belongs under SpringBoard. So is there a way to tell which app is active in front of SpringBoard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are way easier than what would one think. I found out that this brings the answer:

```
SBApplication *front = [[objc_getClass("SpringBoard") sharedApplication] _accessibilityFrontMostApplication];
NSString *runner = front.bundleIdentifier;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `-(NSString*)topApplication` method in `BKSWorkspace` class which returns bundle identifier of a top-most application. In order to get a valid instance of `BKSWorkspace` you need to hook it's `-(id)init` method to retain and store an instance for yourself. SpringBoard stores these instances in such a way that you can't access them without hooking `init`.

Comment: I guess that would work, but init was not needed. What I did was: `SBApplication *front = [[objc_getClass("SpringBoard") sharedApplication] _accessibilityFrontMostApplication];
    NSString *runner = front.bundleIdentifier;`